# Processing - method stops drawing circles

Tags: processing, draw

we have a problem again. We are drawing a bunch of circles. In the middle of one of these drawingCountry Methods it suddenly doesn't draw circles anymore. Also following drawingCountry Methods don't draw circles anymore, but they still get called. We tested it by inserting println("test"). Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Our code looks similar to this:

```
public void drawRussia(){
  canvas.ellipseMode(CORNER);
  canvas.ellipse(705*factorWidth, 149*factorHeight, 75, 75);
  canvas.ellipse(629.5*factorWidth, 161.5*factorHeight, 75, 75);
  canvas.ellipse(523*factorWidth, 164*factorHeight, 75, 75);
  canvas.ellipse(562*factorWidth, 244*factorHeight, 10, 10);
  canvas.ellipse(555*factorWidth, 253*factorHeight, 10, 10);
 //--------------------------stops drawing circles -------------------
  canvas.ellipse(720*factorWidth, 223*factorHeight, 15, 15);
  canvas.ellipse(673*factorWidth, 116*factorHeight, 50, 50);
  canvas.ellipse(777*factorWidth, 121*factorHeight, 75, 75);
```

}

After drawRussia(), there are similar methods following (which don't draw). Before everything works well.

Is there some kind of buffer, or limit in drawing ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think some more information is needed. How does your `setup()` method looks like? What is `width` and `height` of screen? What is `factorWidth` value? Do you use `noLoop()` in `setup()` or allow animation?

Comment: In other words: post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8410/method-stops-drawing-circles